# Insert the value in a table taking from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table tab1 and tab2. In tab1 i am storing the user_id and quiz_id(quiz_id is primary key) and in the tab2 i want to store the question for the quiz where quiz_id is the same for user_id in second table

Comment: And the quesrtion is exactly?

Comment: Do you have data in your tables or you want to create ?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tab2    
    (select quiz_id from tab1 where user_id = 123), ...
```

Comment: i HAVE TO PERFORM BOTH THE INSERTION AT THE SAME TIME MEANS  FIRST I HAVE TO INSERT THE USER_ID AND QUIZ_ID AND THEN USING THE QUIZ_ID I HAVE TO INSERT THE QUESTION

Comment: You can't insert into 2 tables with 1 statement. you need 2 insert statements.